# Using templatetags dynamically

Tags: javascript, django

Is it possible to use templatetags dynamically using javascript?

Basically I want to sub in a variable into a templatetag based on what a user clicks on.

I have javascript to detect what they click on... but because Django renders the templatetags on the server, I'm not sure how to properly do this or if it's possible.

CODE EXAMPLE:

`{% avatar user %}` where `user` is a variable and is dependent on what the user clicks on.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the templates are rendered on the server, while the javascript code is executed on the client. So in short it's not possible.

However, you can split a page into several templates, and use AJAX on the client to construct the complete page. Then when a user clicks your button you make an AJAX call with whatever arguments you want, and get the new rendered template from the server to replace the existing part of the web-page.